# How can I know which observable has changed in combineLatest in RxAndroid?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am using
`Flowable.combineLatest(query,params)` for listening query change and some param change
but now I want to introduce pagination and listen to offset changes , but the problem here is when query is changing I need to reset offset.
Wondering how can I achieve it with RxAndroid?
Basically we observe 3 or more objects (query, offset, connectionChange)
what I want to achieve is listen changes of any of the observables + when query is changed update the value for offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see where the value came from, you have to tag the values in some fashion, which requires per-source transformation. For example:

```kotlin
data class Tuple<T>(val value: T, val index: Long) { ... }

Flowable.defer {
    var indices: Array<Long>(4) { 0 }
    var latests: Array<Long>(4) { 0 }
    Flowable.combineLatest(
        source1.map { Tuple(it, indices[0]++) },
        source2.map { Tuple(it, indices[1]++) },
        source3.map { Tuple(it, indices[2]++) },
        source4.map { Tuple(it, indices[3]++) },
        { tuple1, tuple2, tuple3, tuple4 -> 
            
             if (tuple1.index != latests[0]) {
                 // first source changed
             }
             if (tuple2.index != latests[1]) {
                 // second source changed
             }
             if (tuple3.index != latests[2]) {
                 // third source changed
             }
             if (tuple4.index != latests[3]) {
                 // fourth source changed
             }

             latests[0] = tuple1.index
             latests[1] = tuple2.index
             latests[2] = tuple3.index
             latests[3] = tuple4.index
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is clear this piece of code.
because here you have {tuple ->if()...}
but with combineLatest it  will be {tuple1, tuple2,tuple3,tuple4 -> ...}
as you have 4 sources

Comment: Right, forgot about that. Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for the great answer you gave me a while ago. I would like to have better understanding why we user defer here?

Comment: In case you reuse/retry the whole `Flowable` the indices and latests would be confined to one subscriber and not shared across multiple subscribers.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd.

Comment: I have another question which is connected to the above described Rx chain , but not related to the question above. I hope it is fine to ask it here!
combineLatest return Flowable<Data> and based on one of the properties Data object is holding I need to call either flatmap or switchmap .I don't know how should I continue the chain . Another solution that came to my mind , I can have AtomicBoolean property which I can define next to indices and then I can pass that atomichInteger to compose() where based on the property I can decide what to call flatmap or switchmap ,wdyt ?

Comment: here is the question 
that I have created, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221282/wondering-what-is-the-best-way-to-continue-the-following-rx-chain-where-i-need

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check something here

[Pagination with Rx](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples#14-pagination-with-rx-using-subjects)

https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples#14-pagination-with-rx-using-subjects

Comment: my question is not about how to handle pagination I know that, my question is more about 
we need to observe 3 object changes ,but when query is changed which is one of the 3 object I need to reset the second object .

Comment: OK, you have reference to the 2nd observable object?  if you have then simply subject.next(new value); then you reset it, isn't it?
if you don't not having reference, then you need re-arrange the 2nd object and create subject as its parent, that you can use as reference to manipulate the value somewhere else like you said,

Comment: Flowable.combineLatest(queryFlowable, offsetFlowable, connectionFlowable,
                new Function3<SearchQuery, PaginationData, String, Object>() {

        })

I have something like this , where you mean set subject.next() ?

Comment: can you provide more  details ?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly chain another call just after item has been emitted to the `query` flowable. Registering `doAfterNext` before `Flowable` is being register is probably easiest approach.

```
fun observePublishers(query: Flowable<List<String>>, connectionState: Flowable<Boolean>, offset: Flowable<Int>) {
    val newQuery = query.doAfterNext {
        index = 0
    }
    Flowable.combineLatest(newQuery, connectionState, offset) { queryResult, hasConnection, offsetValue ->
        
    }.subscribe { 
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikola Despotoski . do you mean index here as offset, want to mention  that offset is flowable here

Comment: I assumed that's an integer that you want to reset. If you want to emit new item on `offset` flowable,  you might need to get reference of the publisher of that flowable.

Comment: For simplicity I said that , but it flowable<PaginationData> that I need to reset offset and some other data/

Comment: ^ Can you please provide a piece of code to make clear