# Wondering what is the best way to continue the following Rx chain ,where I need to decide to call either flatmap or switchmap?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a Flowable object `Flowable<Data>`based on the Data property I need to continue the chain  either using `flatmap` or `switchmap` operator and where I will call the method which returns Flowable.

```
Data(a:boolean, str:String)

return Flowable.defer(
                () -> {
                    final int[] indices = new int[3];
                    //AtomicBoolean state = new AtomicBoolean(false);
                    return Flowable.combineLatest(a,b,c,()->{
                        return Flowable<Data>; })
```

Here, after combineLatest, where I have Flowable I want to decide based on a property to call either flatmap() or switchmap(). Wondering how can I continue.

One thing that came to my mind is following, to have the AtomicBoolean and then
I can do the following pass to compose() but I am not sure if this is a right approach?

```
.compose(new SwitchMapWithFlatMap(state.get()))
```

Comment: Depends on what you try to achieve.

Comment: When I use switchmap I want to cancel the previous requests, and with flatmap keeping the previous request . That is my goal. the methods that I use returns Flowable<MetaData>

Comment: So you want to toggle between the two modes? When do you want this toggle to happen?

Comment: I think it should happen after combinelatest.  
We can also call it in combineLatest as well , but not sure if that is a good idea or not or how we can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have the `combineLatest` reference and apply your choice of operator conditionally:

```java
return Flowable.defer(() -> {
    final int[] indices = new int[3];
    //AtomicBoolean state = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Flowable<Data> f = Flowable.combineLatest(a, b, c, (x, y, z) -> {
                            return Flowable<Data>; 
                       });
    if (state.get()) {
        return f.flatMap(w -> ... );
    }
    return f.switchMap(w -> ...);
});
```

Comment: yes, I think I was saying the same but just using compose and passing state. 
I wasn't sure if passing AtomicBoolean and keeping/sharing the state using the defer, is right ,safe approach or not. But I guess there is nothing to worry  yes when it comes to thread safety?